# What is the volume of a 4D sphere?

Tags: volume, spheres

What is the volume of a 4D sphere? I've seen so many sites that would have answered this question, but all of them have so many numbers that some people (including me) don't understand. So I was hoping somebody here would give me a nice simple explanation.

Comment: $\pi^2 R^4/2$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball

Comment: Deriving the volume inside a 3-sphere is a pretty standard calculation. Could you expand your answer to explain what the problem with it is. Otherwise we're likely to repeat an explanation that you've already found too difficult.

Comment: Is this a physics question?  Seems to me it is mathematics.

Answer (score 4):

Let $V_n$ denote the volume of $S^n$. The projection $\pi(x_1, \dots, x_{n+1}) \to (x_1 \dots, x_n)$ maps each slice $\{(x_1, \dots, x_n, t)\in S^n\}$ onto $(1 - t^2)^{1/2} S^{n-1}$. It follows that
\begin{align*}
V_n &= V_{n-1} \int_{-1}^1 dt\;(1 - t^2)^{(n-1)/2}.
\end{align*}
The cases $n\leq 3$ are well-known, and the integral is not difficult to compute (or Mathematica, etc. will do it uncomplainingly).

Comment: How do you get from $(1 - t^2)^{1/2}S^{n - 1}$ to $V_{n - 1} \int_{- 1}^1 (1 - t^2)^{(n - 1)/2} \, dt$? I assume this term is being integrated over $[- 1, 1]$ and Fubini is used, but how is the $V_{n - 1}$ pulled out?

Answer (score 2):

Try with [this](http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/watkins/ndim.htm) explanation. Here the main result for a 4-dimensions sphere:

$$V_4(R) = \frac{1}{2} π^2 R^4$$